# Creating an array without numpy

Tags: python

In my homework, numpy usage wasn't allowed but I realize that just now. I have to delete all the np.array() components and define an array without using them. I couldn't find a way. For example, I have to get arr like this:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
 [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
 [28 29 30 31 32 33 34]
 [35 36 37 38 39 40 41]
 [42 43 44 45 46 47 48]]
```

However, when I delete this part: arr = np.array(range(0,N*N))

arr.shape = N,N

and try to use something else, I cannot get a matrix like this and cannot shape it as in the above without using numpy. I am really stuck here.

```
import numpy as np

def rotate_clockwise(x):
    return x[::-1].T


def find(element, matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            if matrix[i][j] == element:
                return (i+1, j+1)
N = int(input())
S = int(input())

arr = np.array(range(0,N*N))

arr.shape = N,N
for i in range(S):
    a,b,c = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    arr[a - 1:a + c, b - 1:b + c] = rotate_clockwise(arr[a - 1:a + c, b - 1:b + c])


M = int(input())
items = np.array(range(0,M))
for i in range(M):
    danscisayisi=int(input())
    items[i]=(danscisayisi)

for i in range(0, len(items)):
    items[i] = int(items[i])
noktalar = np.array(range(0,M))
for i in range(M):
    coord=(find(items[i],arr))
    result = " ".join(str(x) for x in coord)
    print(result)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want is an array `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34], [35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41], [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48]]`?

Comment: Oh no, I currently get that array and I want to get:(its the first block of text on my post, a square array)

[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
 [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
 [28 29 30 31 32 33 34]
 [35 36 37 38 39 40 41]
 [42 43 44 45 46 47 48]]

Comment: Do you actually need an array (a contiguous memory region of native types) or just a sequence of sequences of numbers?

Answer (score 4):

You could use nested lists instead. One convenient way to construct them is with (nested) list comprehensions, e.g.

```py
n_rows, n_cols = 7, 7

pseudo_array = [[row * n_cols + col for col in range(n_cols)] 
                for row in range(n_rows)]
pseudo_array
```

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
 [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
 [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
 [35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41],
 [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48]]
```

**Edit**: Note that NumPy arrays have commas too, it's just that they also have their own representation method, so that `print()` doesn't show the commas. If you want to do something similar for your nested lists, you could define your own printing function, e.g.

```py
def print_array(a):
    """ Take a nested list a and print it like a NumPy array. """
    for i, row in enumerate(a):
        if i == 0:
            first_char = '['
        else: 
            first_char = ' '
        if i == len(a) - 1:
            last_char = ']'
        else: 
            last_char = ''    
        print(first_char + '[' + 
              ' '.join(str(i) for i in row) + ']' + last_char)
        
print_array(pseudo_array)
```

```
[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [7 8 9 10 11 12 13]
 [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
 [28 29 30 31 32 33 34]
 [35 36 37 38 39 40 41]
 [42 43 44 45 46 47 48]]
```

As you see, it looks almost like a printed NumPy array, only the pretty column alignment isn't implemented yet.

Comment: it is close to what I'm trying to get but I have to get it without having any coma, like in my first block of code on my post. I have written rest of my code under that specification, however at the last minute I have to edit it due to the limitations of module usage